# Is Handles tag name allways a full action name point to controller action?

Tags: magento-1.9

Despite `<default>` is **Handles tag** name allways a full action name point to controller action or it's just a unique name register somewhere else?

`<helloworld_index_index />`

`app/code/.../Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php::indexAction`

Answer (score 3):

Magento layout handles are a bit enigmatic, and this is a great question.

The controller's `loadLayout()` method adds the handles to be loaded:

```
/**
 * Load layout by handles(s)
 *
 * @param   string|null|bool $handles
 * @param   bool $generateBlocks
 * @param   bool $generateXml
 * @return  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
 */
public function loadLayout($handles = null, $generateBlocks = true, $generateXml = true)
{
    // if handles were specified in arguments load them first
    if (false!==$handles && ''!==$handles) {
        $this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle($handles ? $handles : 'default');
    }

    // add default layout handles for this action
    $this->addActionLayoutHandles();

    $this->loadLayoutUpdates();

    if (!$generateXml) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->generateLayoutXml();

    if (!$generateBlocks) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->generateLayoutBlocks();
    $this->_isLayoutLoaded = true;

    return $this;
}
```

The above is code from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`. You can see that unless another handle is specified in the call to the function, the default handle will be loaded.

The `addActionLayoutHandles()` method then includes the rest of the handles, with the controller action handle being of note. The method looks like this:

```
public function addActionLayoutHandles()
{
    $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();

    // load store handle
    $update->addHandle('STORE_'.Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode());

    // load theme handle
    $package = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package');
    $update->addHandle(
        'THEME_'.$package->getArea().'_'.$package->getPackageName().'_'.$package->getTheme('layout')
    );

    // load action handle
    $update->addHandle(strtolower($this->getFullActionName()));

    return $this;
}
```

You can see that there are store- and theme-specific handles included as well. Any handle can be loaded on any page with the `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::addHandle()` method.

While the Layout system will automagically include the controller handle, layout handles are really just unique strings specified elsewhere, like your second option in your question.

Comment: also, as I found it now, if  a handle name `foo` not represents controller then to load it in a controller I must put it name in `$this->loadLayout('foo')->renderLayout();`